# event.target.id or $(this).attr("id") not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am trying to pull the id of a div element, however none of the methods described in other threads have worked. This includes:

```
$(".icon").on('click', function(event){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log(id);
});

$(".icon").on('click', function(event){
  var id = event.target.id;
  console.log(id);
});

$(".icon").click(function(event){
  var id = event.target.id
  console.log(id);
});

$(".icon").click(function(event){
  var id = this.id;
  console.log(id);
});
```

The only way I have successfully been able to pull the div's ID is when I used an onclick function in the HTML to connect to an html-bound JS function. (Although this is because the function is defined prior to the HTML element, which is not possible with the external file I need to call at the end of the document.)

```
<script>
function getId(element) {
console.log(element.id);
}
</script>
<div class="icon" id="test" onclick="getId(this)">text goes here</div>
```

The exact issue I am getting is that the console.log() of the variable 'id' is either empty or reads 'undefined', despite clearly having an ID and it working when it is HTML-bound.

I need to be able to read the div's id when clicked from an external JS file called at the end of the HTML code.

If it helps, the div elements have a parent div.

Comment: can you create a working fiddle? or add complete code along with html

Comment: You gotta put your script at the BOTTOM of the page after the html or use the document.ready() method. Your trying to access information that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## jQuery:

```js
$(".icon").on('click', function(event){
  var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon" id="test">text goes here</div>
```

When binding a click event with jQuery, the passed argument is the `click` event. If `console.log`-ed it will reveal the DOM element inside the `.target` property. `event.target` is a DOM element. So you can get the id by using `event.target.id` or, to stick to `jQuery` methods, one should use `.attr('id')` on the jQuery wrapper around the DOM element: `$(event.target).attr(id)`.

As [charliefl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) noted in the comments, this is prone to error when a child of the element is clicked, as `target` will be the child while the click is bound on the parent (and the child might not have an `id` at all). To make sure you are getting the `id` of the parent, use `.closest('.icon')` on the `event.target` (which finds the closest ancestor, including the current element, with the class `icon`).

So, an improved jQuery method would be:

```js
$(".icon").on('click', function(event){
  var id = $(event.target).closest('.icon').attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon" id="test">text goes here</div>
```

## JavaScript:

```js
getId = function(el) {
  console.log(el.id);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon" id="test" onclick="getId(this)">text goes here</div>
```

When binding using `onclick` attribute, the first argument of the function is not the `event`, but the `DOM element`. If the element has an `id` attribute, it will be returned by calling the `.id`. Otherwise, calling `.id` will return `undfined`. (in JavaScript, DOM elements are objects and each of their attributes are properties, with the notable exception of `class`, which can be accessed via the `.classList` property, which in turn features handy methods like: `.add()`, `.remove()`, `.contains()` and `.toggle()`).

The important difference and what you should get from this is that the DOM element is not the same thing as the jQuery wrapper around it. You can always use jQuery methods by wrapping any DOM element in a jQuery wrapper: `$('selector')` and, viceversa, you can access the DOM element from a jQuery wrapper by using `$('selector')[0]`. If the jQuery wrapper is a collection, you can iterate it using `.each()` or you can go directly to one of them using `.eq(index)`. Thus, `document.querySelector('.icon')` is equivalent to `$('.icon').eq(0)[0]`.

Comment: What is meaning of answer when no explanation given? And why would it be any different than `event.target.id`? or `this.id` as in OP code?

Comment: I wanted to provide the fast answer. An ample explanation is not that simple and will probably take me a good while to explain in a helpful way. I love how people downvote perfectly valid answers in SO. A Happy New Year!

Comment: But it is a useless answer without an explanation. how is anyone supposed to know you plan to do more. Still nothing shown is really any different than in question, other than to say "it works"

Comment: I have the bad habbit of giving ample explanations, charlietfl. So I usually provide a fast, correct, answer and than take my time to explain, as my answer is still going to be the first correct one posted. There is nothing wrong with that. Or if it is, go on, downvote all my answers on SO.

Comment: Only voted on what was shown. We can't read minds. The outcome is actually higher quality than most but being the *fastest gun* but  with no details you should expect such reactions

Comment: Don't worry about me. I actually find rep on SO pretty useless. My only reason here is to help others learn, as I wouldn't be where I am now if others wouldn't have done the same for me.

Comment: Note one drawback to using `event.target` is if the element has children.... `target` and `this` won't be the same when child is clicked

Comment: `true`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `jQuery` library and add your code in `ready()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".icon").on('click', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    console.log(event.target.id);
  });


  $(".icon").click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log(this.id);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon" id="test">text goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `jquery code` should work fine i guess you are not including `jquery library` that's why only `javascript code` works for you.

Add jquery library and put your code in `doument.ready`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And jquery code

```
$(function () {
  $(".icon").on('click', function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
    });
});
```